# Derivative problem

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I applied the definition of the derivative to find $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3-2x}$ 
the answer was $\frac{2}{(3-2x)^2}$ I tried to check my answer by solving it with power rule of derivative but the answer was $\frac{-1}{(3-2x)^2}$. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hint: Chain rule.

Comment: Don't forget to multiply/divide by inner derivative (in this case $-2$).

Answer (score 0):

After taking the derivative of $\frac{1}{3-2x}$ with respect to 3-2x, you have to multiply by the derivative of 3-2x with respect to x

Answer (score 0):

In the second Chain Rule calculation since the independent variable was 2x you should not forget to multiply with -2 further on.